# Angular2 component styles/css not applied by browser in ngAfterViewInit

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a problem with using some JQuery libary inside my angular 2.0 component. The problem is that this library OwlCarousel is using some measurment `$('element).width()` internally to be applied correctly.

Inside my `ngAfterViewinit` I am creating carousel with `$(this.carousel.nativeElement).owlCarousel(options);`

The problem with that approach is that there is no guarantee, that in this lifecycle styles that angular added to header tag are already interpreted recalculated and applied by borwser.

It results in non-deterministic behaviour. Sometimes carousel is getting good sizes of elements - other times its too fast and size is 0 because, despite that style element is already in head tag of HTML, its not applied by browser. Any advice?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tc-slider',
  styles: [`
    .slide{
      width:100px;
    }
  `],
  template: `  
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div #carousel>
      <div class="slide">1</div>
      <div class="slide">2</div>
      <div class="slide">3</div>
      <div class="slide">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>`,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class SliderComponent {
  @ViewChild('carousel') carousel:ElementRef;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var options:any = {
      mouseDrag: false,
      autoWidth: true
    };
    $(this.carousel.nativeElement).owlCarousel(options);
  }
}
```

$('.slide').width()  is 0 in ngAfterViewInit. most of the time is measured correctly but once on 10 times it has 0 .

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. it was caused by 
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,700');
inside one of my css styles added by angular comonent. this was blocking css interpretation till downloaded from google. when javascript was faster then google respond it result with bad sizes of elements because all css styles below this statement: @import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,700');
 where not impreted and applied by browser yet.